# Laravel docs do a contract vs facade but fail to explain what it is really about

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

from the official docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades

this seems easy to test (the cache class)

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')
         ->with('key')
         ->andReturn('value');

    $this->visit('/cache')
         ->see('value');
}
```

as well in the documentation of facades it is written:

> When building a third-party package that interacts with Laravel, it's
>   better to inject Laravel contracts instead of using facades. Since
>   packages are built outside of Laravel itself, you will not have access
>   to Laravel's facade testing helpers.

I really don't see how this is true. The package very well will access functions of laravel, so I don't see how it should not work with testing?

now in contracts https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/contracts they go on a little philosophical discussion what to use, facades or contracts. Isn't it better to use them together? Because contracts are nothing else than an interface. Now the idea of an interface is not new at all. I don't really get, what is the point about first of all comparing facades and contracts when:

facades are basically a extended class of laravel adding testing possibilities. They hide the implementation though and make it harder to read what functions are available on the class. E.g. you *always* first have to figure out what implementation is used of the facade, to see what methods there are.

contracts on the other hand are nothing else than interfaces. Basically the laravel people telling us "use interfaces". I agree, interfaces are great. But I don't see in what way this relates to facades. They are not related. They are not interchangeable neither.

So what is this all about?

why say "use contracts OR facades" they are not related, and should be used together imho.

An example is the Mail facade:

```
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer
 */
class Mail extends Facade{...
```

so accessing `Mail::` will return an instance of `\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer`

lets look at `\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer`

```
class Mailer implements MailerContract, MailQueueContract
{
```

nothing else than a class implementing a contract aka interface.

What exactly are they trying to tell us?

Answer (score 1):

> third-party package

is key term here to consider. Not every package is used with Laravel only.

> The package very well will access functions of laravel

Is that true if I use CodeIgniter? Nope.

Now if you build a package *specifically* for Laravel, then by all means, use facades all day.

The whole point of this is to not couple yourself tightly with a single framework.

Comment: so if I want to create a general package for everyone. That is not generally the case for me though and most package I use are designed for laravel. I understand that what taylor reuses is oftne not made for laravel. So using a facade makes it impossible to create a 3rd party package for codeigniter? https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/ I dont think so. So even your point that seems valid, is not really valid.  why facade VERSUS contract: i guess they wanted to say: you can configure both. why call it contract and not interface though? no clue

Comment: That sitepoint.com example you linked literally does a composer require for Illuminates support class. So pretty much still entirely dependent on the facade. They even go step by step setting them up as Laravel does. I get what you're trying to say though, yes facades can be used outside of Laravel, but the underlying pieces are still needed (coupled to Illuminate, in this case). As far as the contract vs interface? Who knows... maybe Taylor thinks contract conveys the meaning better. There really is not difference besides that.